# Angular 4 Form Validations Order

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way to order the form validations?

For example: if I have 3 validations (required, regex, custom)

Comment: I've always assumed they run in the order you specify them in the validators array. They don't?

Comment: Jup, as there is no other way of ordering them specifically, they are ordered by array order. This happens super fast, so if something was to happen in between i suggest you tell us waht you want to achieve.